# Laplace Transform: $g(x)=a\sin(x)+\int_0^x \sin(x-u)g(u) du$

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution

$$g(x)=a\sin(x)+\int_0^x \sin(x-u)g(u)du$$

I need to find $g(x)$

I believe I need to use Laplace Transform with this in mind (Convolution Thm): $$(f*g)(x)= \int_0^x f(x-t)g(t)dt$$

However I don't understand how to do this problem.

Comment: used the edits, thanks guys!!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Solve for $g$?

Comment: @PatrickStevens Hi, yes, sorry for being unclear, I edited and made sure to put "I need to find g(x)"

Comment: @Alex Provost  Hi, I believe I made it clear now. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have
$$ g = a \cdot\mathord\sin + \mathord\sin * g $$
With $\def\L{\mathscr L}\L$ denoting the Laplace transform, we have
$$ \L(g) = \L(a \cdot\mathord\sin + \mathord\sin * g) = a\L(\sin) + \L(\sin)\L(g) $$
as $\L(f*g) = \L(f)\L(g)$, hence 
$$ \L(g)\bigl(1-\L(sin)\bigr) = a\L(\sin) \iff  \L(g) = \frac {a\L(sin)}{1-\L(\sin)} $$
As $\L(\sin)(s) = \frac 1{1+s^2}$, we have $1-\L(\sin)(s) = \frac{1+s^2-1}{1+s^2}$
$$ \L(g)(s) = \frac{a (1+s^2)}{(1+s^2)\cdot s^2} = \frac{a}{s^2} $$
Hence $g(t) = at$.

Comment: The only problem that I see is that the integration is performed on $[0,x]$ and not on $[0, \infty)$, so that integral is not exactly a convolution. Of course, you could try to multiply one of the two functions inside the integral by $\rm{id}_{[0,x]}$ (the characteristic function of $[0,x]$), in which case your equation could look like $g = a \sin + ({\rm id}_{[0,x]} \sin) * g$, which is a different business.

Comment: @AlexM. This integral is a convolution of functions $[0,\infty) \to \mathbf R$, for $\int_0^\infty f(t)g(x-t) \,dt$ is not well-defined for such functions, if as $g(x-t)$ only makes sense for $t \le x$. So the convolution of such functions is usually defined as $$ (f*g)(x) = \int_0^x f(t)g(x-t) \,dt $$

Comment: You are right. I come from a Fourier transform background (integration done on the whole space), so apparently I have found myself trespassing into Laplace forbidden zone... I'll leave my comment here, though, since it is harmless.

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I understand how to do it completely now!!